# Android how to force download the file by web browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I use this code in my app to download a video file by web browser (each one that user select: chrome, dolphin or... )

```
   View BtnDownload = (View)rootView.findViewById(R.id.BtnDownload);
   BtnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
           intent.setData(url);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   });
```

It works well on my phone (browser prompt for download), but when i test it on another phone it goes to play (show) the video by auto selected browser.

Now, my question:

- How can i force *download file* instead *view file* by web browser?
- I want another action like `Intent.ACTION_Download` instead of `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.
- I want prevent using complex methods like download the file by a downloader class. Is it possible achieve this by a trick?

---

**EDIT**

What happen when i press the button:

For example on my phone, when i press the button it open dolphin browser and dolphin prompt me to download the video file but on another phone when i press the button it open a browser and goes to play the video.

Comment: Android doesn't distinguish what happens with the URL when it comes to the intents, it simply detects what you applications you have that can perform the implicit intent request. You can simply download the file from the URL via code if you want to force it, no need to even prompt the user with an intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i force download file instead view file by web browser?

There is no requirement for any browser to download a file based upon an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. There are many browsers for Android, both pre-installed and installed by users.

> I want another action like Intent.ACTION_Download instead of Intent.ACTION_VIEW.

There is no requirement for any browser to offer any specific action that forces the download of a file.

Comment: @CommonsWarem, but how can i download the video file? I wrote download on the Button in my app then my codes must download the file for user by a safe way. My mentioned codes in the question have problem (it play the video sometimes). Please give me an absolute solution to download the video file in android download folder.

Comment: @RAM: "but how can i download the video file?" -- use `DownloadManager`, `HttpURLConnection`, or a third-party HTTP client library (e.g., OkHttp, Volley).

Comment: @CommonsWarem, I want try [this code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java) of you. Is it ok?

Comment: @RAM: I would use [this version of the project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/Download), as the copy you pointed to is over four years old at this point. Most of the code should be the same.

Comment: Ok @CommonsWarem, thank you for this answer and all of your answers in stackoverflow about android coding. I like you...